# 'User' object has no attribute 'split' when using select_related

Tags: python, django

I am getting very strange error when I am using select_related. I have created a model which extends the auth_user table. For your reference I am pasting the model below

```
class BasicDetails(models.Model):
   username = models.OneToOneField(User)
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Name")
   sex = models.CharField(max_length = 10, verbose_name = "Sex", choices = GENDER_CHOICES)
   dob = models.DateField(verbose_name = "Date of Birth")
   mothertongue = models.CharField(max_length = 20, verbose_name = "Mother Tongue", choices = LANGUAGES_CHOICES)
```

The above table has only one record and when I run the below query in the django shell its working fine and I am able to retrieve the values.

```
basicdetails = BasicDetails.objects.select_related('auth_user__username',request.user)
```

However when I input the same query in my views and template I am getting below error.

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
111.response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/vikramt/python/OpenMatrimony/wedding/views.py" in myprofile
160.basicdetails = BasicDetails.objects.select_related('auth_user__username',request.user)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in select_related
173.return self.get_query_set().select_related(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in select_related
686.obj.query.add_select_related(fields)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in     add_select_related
1759.for part in field.split(LOOKUP_SEP):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in inner
185.return func(self._wrapped, *args)
```

Exception Type: AttributeError at /myprofile/
   Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute 'split'

Can someone help me on this context. I couldn't able to understand what was the problem. Any clues?

-Vikram

Comment: Somewhere you're passing a User object, whatever that is (some ORM model?) to some function or method that, somewhere down the line, is expecting a string.

Comment: User object is nothing but django inbuilt auth system. However when I run the same query I am getting the results properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`select_related` expects its parameters to be strings. Your `request.user` object is not a string, and don't have a `split()` method. That is why an AttributeError is being raised.

But the tricky part is that, as you said, when you did the same thing from inside a shell session, it worked. I would risk to say that in that shell context, `request.user` was somehow a string, or was behaving like a string.

Anyway, why are you passing an User instance to select_related? I mean, what do you want to achieve by doing that?

**Edit**

Ok, if you want to retrieve the record of BasicDetails for the current logged
in user, you should be using the `filter` method. It's used to
filter a queryset:

```
basicdetails = BasicDetails.objects.filter(username=request.user)
```

The `select_related` method is used to tell the ORM to do something
like a SQL join to populate the specified related columns of the results.

And I would recommend you to rename your `username` column to
something more clear. It's a relation to the user table, so you should call it
just `user`.

Comment: Now I have added str(request.user) and I am able to get rid of the error but no values are displaying. I am trying to retrieve the record of BasicDetails table for the currently logged_in user.

Comment: Thanks for your response. For changing the `username` column I should edit the auth module which is not recommendable.